# Counting total number of occurrence of pattern in string

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching, match

I have a string `caaab`. I want to count total number of occurrence of pattern `aa` in this string. It should be two.

```
[c**aa**ab]
[ca**aa**b]
```

I am using `(caaab'.match(/aa/g)||[]).length` but it is returning only `1` not `2`.

How to do this in javascript. Any solution.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a positive look ahead for matching, because it does not consume a missing step.

```js
console.log(('caaab'.match(/a(?=a)/g) || []).length);
```

Comment: You could also use a positive look behind `(?<=aa)`

Comment: @S.Walker, actually not in javascript, because it's not implemented.

Comment: Javascript does not support positive look behind?

Comment: @S.Walker, jes, not today.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is the overlap in patterns.

If the pattern to search for is a fixed string, not a regex,
then you can call `indexOf` repeatedly,
updating the start index after every match.

```
var count = function (s, t) {
  var count = 0, index = 0;
  while (true) {
    index = s.indexOf(t, index);
    if (index === -1) break;
    count++;
    index++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

With this implementation, `count('caaab', 'aa')` will return 2.